# Background-image with repeat has to stop when there are other background-images

Tags: html, css, background-image

The content div of my website has a unique background with all kind of layer styles. In HTML/CSS I can just take the background from photoshop and use it as a background-image. 
My problem is that the content div's height is variable. To solve this I took the top pixels and set them at the top, one pixel row in the center which has a repeat-y and the bottom pixels and place them at the bottom. This works but the middle background-image has to start after the top background-image and before the bottom background-image.

```
div#content{
    background: url('contentbghead.png') top center no-repeat, 
                url('contentbgfoot.png') bottom center no-repeat, 
                url('contentbgmid.png') 0px 10px repeat-y;
    width:680px;
    height:300px;
}
```

My result can be found here: http://tinypic.com?ref=30muazs

Comment: This is a CSS3 deal, that not all browsers support... sorry to say but it's going to be browser specific, or else it will fail all parameters, except for the first or last... sometimes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple backgrounds are not supported in CSS2. You'll need multiple divs to achieve what you're looking for.

You can also take a look at some CSS3 methods for multiple backgrounds at:

[Multiple Backgrounds with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

That method, however, does not work in versions of IE older than IE9.

Comment: Isn't it possible with CSS3 without three divs?

Comment: Correct, but as Relic commented above, it does not yet work on all browsers. If you post a picture and/or some more code, we might be able to help you a little better.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with just multiple backgrounds, as each background entry has no relation to another. However, you could achieve this effect using pseudo elements:

```
div#content{
    position:relative;
    background: url('contentbghead.png') top center no-repeat, 
                url('contentbgfoot.png') bottom center no-repeat;
    width:680px;
    height:300px;
}
div#content:before {
    content:"\0020"; font-size:0px;
    display:block; position:absolute; top:10px; left:0px; bottom:10px;
    width: /* Whatever your BG's width is */;
    background:transparent url('contentbgmid.png') repeat-y left top;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

You'll want to take precaution of z-index layering, as it's possible the pseudo element might capture click events if it's layered above your content (for browsers that do not support pointer-events).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve your results using the **:before** and **:after**  **CSS pseudo-elements**.

I have made a code with only one div and used your all  three images in that one div and mid image is also repeatable on **y-axis**.

**Note**   **:before** and **:after** **pseudo-elements** supports till **IE-8**

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content Dummy Content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #content:after {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/5agws.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    content: " ";
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 680px;
}

#content:before {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/P7jL5.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    content: " ";
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    width: 680px;
}

#content {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vAqRU.png") repeat-y 0 0;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 680px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;

}
```

see the demo for better understanding :- http://jsfiddle.net/5Lkmr/40/

Comment: I think it is a pretty neat solution for the problem in question, especially when IE8 needs to be supported. Can this be used for horizontal repeat with fixed left and right images?